# Box position after webkit-transform rotation

Tags: ipad, safari, webkit

Does anyone know how to get the displayed top left hand corner of a rotated box after using a rotation with webkit-transform?

So, for example, I draw a box ask for the top left corner, rotate the box 270 degrees for example, then how to I query for the position of the "new" top left corner, which in this case is effectively the original bottom right corner ...

I've tried using jQuery to check the offset().top and offset().left but it seems jQuery is clever enough to know that the container is rotated, and I get back the original top left hand corner which I don't want in this case.

I guess I could track the rotations and then always ask for the correct offsets, but I think it would be a little more robust if this was possible.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try grabbing the top left corner as a point (original not bounding box), then the `transform-origin`, the `width` and the `height` as well as the `transform` style property.

To get the original top left point of an element in webkit use this function:

```
function getOffset(el){

        if(el.context!==undefined)
            el = el[0]; //remove the jquery wrapper if there is one

        var x = 0, y = 0;

        while(el && !isNaN(el.offsetLeft) && !isNaN(el.offsetTop)) {

            x+=el.offsetLeft;
            y+=el.offsetTop;
            el = el.offsetParent;
    }

    return {left:x,top:y};

}
```

If the transform origin is a specific amount, such as `50px 30px` then you can use it out right as the point to rotate the top-left by. If it is, however, a percentage, use the width and height to figure out the point to rotate by. `e.g. 20% 60px would be (width/5,60)`

To get the angle out of the element (if you don't already know it) you can run this function

```
function getRotation(el,returnType,recurse) {

        el = el.context!==undefined?el[0]:el;

        var styl = el.style,
            tran = styl.transform || styl.webkitTransform || styl.mozTransform || 'rotate(0deg)',
            rgx = tran.match(/\(([\d\.]+)\w/i),
            ang = parseFloat(rgx[1])||0,
            type = rgx[2]||"deg";

        recurse = (recurse===undefined?false:recurse);
        returnType = returnType || "deg";

        if(recurse && el.className.indexOf("limb-piece")!==-1)
            ang += getRotation(el.parentNode,returnType,recurse);

        if(returnType===type)
            return ang;
        else {

            if(type==="deg")
                return ang*(180/Math.PI);
            else
                return ang*(Math.PI/180);
        }

    }
```

Take the `transform-origin` and use this function (p1 is the origin, use [0,0] and p2 is the transform-origin, then angle is the rotation in radians

```
rotatePointAroundPoint : function(p1,p2,ang){

        var s = Math.sin(ang), c = Math.cos(ang),
            x = p1[0] - p2[0], y = p1[1] - p2[1],

            rx = x * c - y * s,
            ry = x * s + y * c,

            ret = [rx+p2[0],ry+p2[1]];

        return ret;

    }
```

Then add the result to your top left calculated from the original and you should have the position of the top-left at any angle.